# Understanding how to use beautifulsoup find() to extract all elements in an html in a particular div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is [the URL](https://socialblade.com/tiktok/top/50/most-followers) for what I am working with.

[image: Sample html]

I am trying to get all the values under `Username` from this html using `soup.find()`. I am not sure how to refer to this `div` as the last `div` I find with an is is `soup.find("div", {"id": "sort-by"}).contents` which returns:

```
['\n',
 <div id="sort-by-container">
 <div id="sort-by-current"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-sort"></i> <span id="sort-by-current-title">Sorted by: Followers</span></div>
 <div class="border-box no-select" id="sort-by-dropdown">
 <div class="sort-by-select" data-sort="most-followers" data-title="Sorted by: Followers">Sort by Followers</div>
 <div class="sort-by-select" data-sort="most-following" data-title="Sorted by: Following">Sort by Following</div>
 <div class="sort-by-select" data-sort="most-uploads" data-title="Sorted by: Uploads">Sort by Uploads</div>
 <div class="sort-by-select" data-sort="most-likes" data-title="Sorted by: Likes">Sort by Likes</div>
 </div>
 </div>,
 '\n',
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>]
```

Ultimately, I am trying to get each row under username `charli d’amelio`, `addison rae` or the content of `<a href""> 
[image]

This is the full code I have tied so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('Top 50 TikTok users sorted by Followers - Socialblade TikTok Stats _ TikTok Statistics.html') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
soup.find('title').contents
soup.find("div", {"id": "sort-by"}).contents
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you have already tried. What's the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all the names under the "Username" column, you can use the [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS Selector: `div div:nth-of-type(n+5) > div > a`.

To use a CSS Selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find_all()`.

In your example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("file.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(file.readlines()), "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("div div:nth-of-type(n+5) > div > a"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
charli d’amelio
addison rae
Bella Poarch
Zach King
TikTok
...
```

Comment: Nice use of `n`-arithmetic!

Comment: @MendelG could you please explain how you get `5` for the Username and how to get the number for the rest of the columns?

Comment: I am interested in knowing if there is any way to parse the table, given that it is not in a table format in html.

Comment: @NazaninZinouri I suggest posting your query as a new question on stackoverflow.